# MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway with JAXB marshaller throws error

Tags: java, spring, jaxb, spring-integration

I'm using spring-integration 4.1.2-RELEASE, and am having a bit of problems with a `MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway`. I'm attempting to make a SOAP call to a SOAP webservice, having used JAXB to generate the object representation of the wsdl.

My auto wiring and flow looks like this:

```java
@Autowired
MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway securityService;

@Autowired
HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler documentService;

@Bean
IntegrationFlow getDocument() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("entryPointChannel")
            .handle(securityService)
            .handle(documentService)
            .get();
}
```

It's the `securityService` bean that's the issue. Here's the definition:

```java
@Value("${evry.services.security.endpoint}")
String securityEndpoint;
@Value("${org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias}")
String user;
@Value("${org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password}")
String password;

@Bean
MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway securityService() {
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setContextPath("securityServices.wsdl");
    MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway securityGateway = new MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway(
            securityEndpoint, marshaller, marshaller
    );

    Wss4jSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor = new Wss4jSecurityInterceptor();
    try {
        securityInterceptor.setSecurementSignatureCrypto(new CryptoFactoryBean().getObject());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementActions("Timestamp Signature");
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementSignatureKeyIdentifier("DirectReference");
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementSignatureUser(user);
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementPassword(password);
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementTimeToLive(300000);
    securityInterceptor.setTimestampPrecisionInMilliseconds(true);

    securityGateway.setInterceptors(securityInterceptor);


    return securityGateway;
}
```

When the call is made, this is (part of) the error output:

```java
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap nor any of its super class is known to this context.
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getBeanInfo(JAXBContextImpl.java:567)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:467)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:308)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:236)
```

It seems to me that the spring-integration framework is somehow mucking up the response type that JAXB expects, but i can't figure out how to fix this. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a case of lack of thought on my part. I needed a transformer in front of the `MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway` to translate from the `LinkedMultiValueMap` coming from the `entryPointChannel` into the object the JAXB marshaller was expecting.